# how to persist highcharts tooltip on mouse hover within it

Tags: javascript, highcharts

> I am having a situation where i have huge loads of data to be shown in the highcharts tooltip.
> I have given auto scroll for the tooltip which gives a scroll bar to the right extreme of the tooltip.
> Now, when i move the mouse to the scroll bar of the tooltip the tooltip gets fade or points to the other bars tooltip.
> How can i persist the tooltip without fading when the mouse is over the tooltip.

Note: I can scroll using the mouse scroll action but need to use the scroll bar of the tooltip.

```js
var toolTip = [
  ['INC0841115', 'INC0841232', 'INC0841273', 'INC0841281', 'INC0841282', 'INC0841291', 'INC0841315', 'INC0841329', 'INC0841115', 'INC0841232', 'INC0841273', 'INC0841281', 'INC0841343', 'INC0841351', 'INC0841354', 'INC0841356', 'INC0841386', 'INC0841392', 'INC0841408'],
  ['INC0841670', 'INC0841700'], 
  '0', 
  '0', 
  '0', 
  ['INC0842488', 'INC0842546', 'INC0842548', 'INC0841115', 'INC0841232', 'INC0841273', 'INC0841281', 'INC0842568', 'INC0842569', 'INC0842753', 'INC0842768'],
  ['INC0842815', 'INC0842817', 'INC0842891', 'INC0841115', 'INC0841232', 'INC0841273', 'INC0841281', 'INC0841115', 'INC0841232', 'INC0841273', 'INC0841281', 'INC0842897'],
  ['INC0843582'],
  ['INC0843792', 'INC0843984', 'INC0843997'], 
  '0', 
  '0', 
  ['INC0844516', 'INC0844536', 'INC0841115', 'INC0841232', 'INC0841273', 'INC0841281', 'INC0841115', 'INC0841232', 'INC0841273', 'INC0841281', 'INC0841115', 'INC0841232', 'INC0841273', 'INC0841281', 'INC0841115', 'INC0841232', 'INC0841273', 'INC0841281', 'INC0841115', 'INC0841232', 'INC0841273', 'INC0841281', 'INC0844819', 'INC0845456']
];

$(function() {

  Highcharts.Tooltip.prototype.hide = function() {};

  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Sample',
      x: -20 //center
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
      ]
    },
    legend: {
      layout: 'vertical',
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'middle',
      borderWidth: 0
    },
    tooltip: {
      useHTML: true,
      pointFormatter: function() {
        var string = '<div class = "cDiv">';
        Highcharts.each(toolTip[this.series.data.indexOf(this)], function(p) {
          string += p + '</a><br>'
        })
        return "Incident<br>" + string + "</div><br />";
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Sample',
      data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
    }]
  });
});
```

CSS for the tooltip scroll

```css
.highcharts-tooltip>span {
  pointer-events: auto !important
}

.cDiv {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/d29cy8aj/

Comment: Hi @Arun Kumar, I have tested your example and it seems to work correctly. I did not notice the described behavior.

Comment: Are you able to click the tooltip scrollbar with your mouse pointer? @ppotaczek

Comment: Yes, I am. Tested in Chrome v83.0.4103.97 and Firefox v77.0.1.